# Background image loads too slowly and appears only then when screen is already rendered

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, native-base

When I include all the content inside  (means image works as a View) that image loads to slow. When you navigate to that screen everything is there but image loads quite late and that screen looks like very unprofessional because of that. I have many screens where image used as a full screen background and all those screens have the same behavior. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: is these images are assets?

Comment: did you solve the problem?